# Scala not working in windows linux subsystem

Tags: linux, windows, scala

I installed regular old Scala using apt-get in the WLS, but whenever I try to run scala in the command line to get the REPL, all i can do is type is couple charecters before keyboard input stops registering. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: A year later, with updates, do you still see this problem?